# Which CSS standard is supported by QWidget setStyleSheet?

Tags: qt, css, stylesheet, qwidget

As far as I understand, QtWidgets can be styled via CSS using the method setStyleSheet.

See reference: [QtWidgets styleSheet](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop)

The problem is I couldn't figure out if it supports CSS3 or since which version of Qt CSS3 capabilities are supported and to which extend.

Any clarifying information highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt stylesheets are not standardized. Not all CSS3 properties are supported by Qt, and some of Qt-supported properties aren't supported by regular browsers. You should look at [Qt Style Sheets Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html) and [other docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html) to know supported features list.

Comment: okay this explains the feeling I had with Qt's stylesheets and CSS. So I presume I shouldn't associate them too directly and rather look at them separated, but related.